# How can I fix the clicking transition from start button to info-box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I've been stuck on this for awhile the action in the console was working, but something is preventing it from transitioning. I think something in the CSS is overriding but I've looked and cannot find the issue.

here is my code, I'm a beginner at JS so I really tried to figure it out, but I was hoping it can be resolved quickly

```
var startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
var infoBox = document.querySelector(".info-box");
var quitButton = document.querySelector(".buttons .quit");
var contButton = document.querySelector(".buttons .restart");
var questionArr = document.getElementById("quiz-box");
var score = document.getElementById("total-que");
var questionId = document.getElementById("option");


//If start button is clicked
startButton.onclick = ()=>{
    infoBox.classList.add("activeInfo");
    console.log("test")
}

//If Exit button is clicked
quitButton.onclick = ()=>{
    infoBox.classList.remove("activeInfo");
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/style.css" />
    <link rel="extra stylesheet" href="./assets/extra.css">
    <title>Coding Quiz Challenge!</title>
</head>

    <body>
        <a id="highScore">View Highscores</a>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div id="questions">
                <h1> Coding Quiz Challenge</h1>
                <ul id="list"></ul>
            </div>
        <!--Info box-->
        <!--START QUIZ BUTTON-->
        <button type="button" id="startButton">Start Quiz</button>
        <div class = "info-box" style.display = "block">
            <div class="info-title">
                <span id="span"><b>⋆ Quiz Information ⋆</b></span>
            </div>
           <div class ="info-text">
            <div class ="info">This test will assess your knowledge of basic JavaScript with 5 multiple choice questions. Click the
                "Start"
                button to begin the quiz. You will have 75 seconds to complete the assessment. Your score will your be your time remaining and the number correct.
            </div>
            <div class = "buttons">
             <button class="quit">Exit Quiz</button> 
             <button class="restart">Continue</button>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
    body {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif
}
.startButton, .info-box, .result-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Highscore top */
#highScore{
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 0;
    color: rgb(208, 76, 204);
    padding-left: 10px;
}

/* Timer */
#timer {
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(253, 253, 253);
    background-color: rgb(232, 142, 226);
    border: inset rgb(208, 76, 204); 
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 12px;
    right: 0;
    padding: 11px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.timer-sec {
    background-color: rgb(255, 245, 245);
    width: 25px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block
    }
    
    /* Start Page - Quiz Information & Start */
    div {
        padding: 5px;
    
    }
    h1 {
        background-color: rgb(239, 200, 239);
        margin-top: 50px;
    border: solid 1px purple;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px
    }
    .container {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 32px 70px 32px 70px;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        background-color: rgba(221, 149, 230, 0.232);
    }
    
    .info{
        text-align: center;
        float: center;
    }
    div.info {
        width: 500px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 6px;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-radius: 5px;
        
    }
    .info-box {
        border-top:2px solid rgb(209, 149, 196) ;
        border-bottom:2px solid rgb(209, 149, 196) ;
        border-radius: 6px;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50% scale(0.9));
    }
    .info-box.activateInfo {
        opacity: 1;  
        pointer-events: auto;
        z-index: 5;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
      }
    .info-title {
        background-color: rgba(240, 190, 243, 0.842);
    }
    /* Start Button */
    #startButton{
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(180, 102, 180);
        height: 50px;
        width: 130px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: inset 10px rgb(168, 93, 168);
        border-width: 3px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;   
    }
    /* Exit & Cont. Buttons */
    button {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(206, 155, 206);
        height: 45px;
        width: 74px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: inset 10px rgb(202, 123, 202);
        border-width: 3px;
        border-radius: 12px; 
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .info-box, .buttons, button, .startButton {
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0,3s ease;
    }
    .button:hover, button.quit:hover, button.restart:hover, .startButton:hover {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(246, 230, 246);
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0,3s ease;
    }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

There's a few syntax errors that I've corrected but the main reason why your button doesn't work is because you've overlaid the div with the class .info-box on top of the button and set its opacity to 0 so it'e effectively a transparent layer over the top of the button that prevents you clicking it. If you set the infobox to display:none then display: inline-block in .activateInfo then it works. See attached.

```js
var startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
var infoBox = document.querySelector(".info-box");
var quitButton = document.querySelector(".buttons .quit");
var contButton = document.querySelector(".buttons .restart");
var questionArr = document.getElementById("quiz-box");
var score = document.getElementById("total-que");
var questionId = document.getElementById("option");



//If start button is clicked
startButton.onclick = () => {
  infoBox.classList.add("activateInfo");
}

//If Exit button is clicked
quitButton.onclick = () => {
  infoBox.classList.remove("activateInfo");
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif
}

.startButton,
.info-box,
.result-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* Highscore top */

#highScore {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 0;
  color: rgb(208, 76, 204);
  padding-left: 10px;
}


/* Timer */

#timer {
  position: absolute;
  color: rgb(253, 253, 253);
  background-color: rgb(232, 142, 226);
  border: inset rgb(208, 76, 204);
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 12px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 11px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.timer-sec {
  background-color: rgb(255, 245, 245);
  width: 25px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block
}


/* Start Page - Quiz Information & Start */

div {
  padding: 5px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: rgb(239, 200, 239);
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: solid 1px purple;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 10px
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px 70px 32px 70px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: rgba(221, 149, 230, 0.232);
}

.info {
  text-align: center;
  float: center;
}

div.info {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.info-box {
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(209, 149, 196);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(209, 149, 196);
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50% scale(0.9));
}

.info-box.activateInfo {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
  pointer-events: auto;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.info-title {
  background-color: rgba(240, 190, 243, 0.842);
}


/* Start Button */

#startButton {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(180, 102, 180);
  height: 50px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: inset 10px rgb(168, 93, 168);
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Exit & Cont. Buttons */

button {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(206, 155, 206);
  height: 45px;
  width: 74px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: inset 10px rgb(202, 123, 202);
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.info-box,
.buttons,
button,
.startButton {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0, 3s ease;
}

.button:hover,
button.quit:hover,
button.restart:hover,
.startButton:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(246, 230, 246);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0, 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<a id="highScore">View Highscores</a>

<div class="container">
  <div id="questions">
    <h1> Coding Quiz Challenge</h1>
    <ul id="list"></ul>
  </div>
  <!--Info box-->
  <!--START QUIZ BUTTON-->
  <button type="button" id="startButton">Start Quiz</button>
  <div class="info-box">
    <div class="info-title">
      <span id="span"><b>⋆ Quiz Information ⋆</b></span>
    </div>
    <div class="info-text">
      <div class="info">This test will assess your knowledge of basic JavaScript with 5 multiple choice questions. Click the "Start" button to begin the quiz. You will have 75 seconds to complete the assessment. Your score will your be your time remaining and the number
        correct.
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="quit">Exit Quiz</button>
        <button class="restart">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Okay so it works with that snippet, but I think something else in the css is inteferring since I added the changes back and still nothing.

Comment: If you check your code vs mine line by line, if've corrected a few syntax errors too that were preventing your code from working.  If you're still having problems drop me a comment.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:5500/homework/04-web-api-codequiz/index.html

Comment: You'll have to put it on codepen or similar. You've sent me a link to localhost and I can't see it as it's on your personal computer.

Comment: the rest of the CSS code exceeds the character limit oof

Comment: Codepen.io is the way to go here. After a few comments the chat box might appear and we can discuss outside stack overflow

Comment: https://jfritsch04.github.io/04-web-api-codequiz/

Comment: The div with class 'results-box' is overlaying the button with opacity: 0 also. I've annotated each change and put it here https://codepen.io/adamuk73/pen/vYjezOE

Comment: thank you sm, I really apperciate this. do I just copy/p the code on the site that you annotated?

Comment: Yep. Just copy and paste in to your project.